# SSIS Foreach Loop: map image variable to which SSIS type?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looping over an ADO recordset using a ForEach Loop Container in SSIS 2008. The recordset contains a column of IMAGE data type, which I mapped to a variable of object type. 
Then, I have an Execute SQL task for inserting data from the loop, but I can't figure out to which data type of the available ones should I map the previous image column. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason you're taking this approach versus using a Data Flow task?

Comment: @billinkc Yes, I need to insert some data, get the assigned id and then reuse it in another insert, so I choose this approach. With the data flow task I don't know how to get the inserted id of certain record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of connection are you using in your Execute SQL task? If its OLE DB then unfortunately there is no way you could pass the Image type. On the other hand if you can create an ADO .Net connection to your database and use it in your Execute SQL task then you would be able to map the image type to Object type. Screenshots below.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I'm using the OleDb connection, that's why there were not any object type. I think I'll end up writing the insert command with .Net code, as performance is critical and don't want to use Ado.Net connections.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar,

If you mean to which SQL Server datatype you should map to, my suggestion would be **varbinary(max)** for the image column.

See here for a using **varbinary** instead of **image**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx

See here for an article that might help you using SSIS with Object datatypes.
http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/03/04/using-object-typed-variables-in-ssis/

Ash

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in the Parameter Mapping view of the Execute SQL Task there is not such a varbinary type. 
https://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/544-image004.jpg