# How to fetch a web image and insert into varbinary(max) using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, image, variables, object, ssis

I am using SSIS to read, shred and store an XML feed. That all works. However, the images referenced in the feed need to be stored in the DB also, so this is what I have done so far, in a new SSIS package:

Used Execute SQL task to get an ADO recordset of my image URLs
Use that recordset in ForEach Loop Container which contains:
    Script task where:
        I read the image URL from the appropriate variable
        I use the Webclient to download the image data from that URL
        I save the image data into an Object SSIS variable
        Execute SQL task where I want to insert my Object variable into a VARBINARY(MAX) field

It is this last step (which I have tried using a few different SSIS components!) that seems to be defeating me and I have searched for two days but cannot find someone doing the same thing (which seems odd). Using the Execute SQL task I have tried using this SQL:

```
insert into [ATOMimagedata]  select @[User::entryid] , @[User::mcid], @[User::NCImgURL], null, @[User::NCImgData]
```

but it won't accept the SQL and I have also tried mapping all the variables to parameters and using:

```
insert into [ATOMimagedata]  values( ?, ?, ?, null, ? )
```

but I cannot find an appropriate data type to use for the image data variable parameter.

So, in summary, I have a loop where I have all my SSIS variables on each iteration, including my image data. **How can I insert them into my table?** I could show more code such as the VB where I load the image variable, but I think other than provide background it doesn't help much with the final hurdle.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893914/ssis-foreach-loop-map-image-variable-to-which-ssis-type) help you?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, after sleeping on it, I came to the conclusion that the data typing etc. for the image/object stuff (to pass the image data out to another task) was just too messy to find the solution and maybe there isn't a solution (no one has come up with one so far).

Sooo, light bulb goes on, doh, why not **write the data into the DB directly from the VB Script?**

So here's my code in case anyone else has the same frustrations that are, actually, easily solved once you take the right tack:

```
    Public Sub Main()

    Dim sqlConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlComm As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim sins As String
    Dim tmpURL As String
    Dim tmpImg As Object
    Dim eid As Long
    Dim mid As Long

    tmpURL = CStr(Me.Dts.Variables("NCImgURL").Value)
    Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient()
        WC.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        tmpImg = WC.DownloadData(tmpURL)
        'Me.Dts.Variables("NCImgData").Value = tmpImg
        eid = CLng(Me.Dts.Variables("entryid").Value)
        mid = CLng(Me.Dts.Variables("mcid").Value)
        'now try to write the image
        sins = "insert into [ATOMimagedata]([entry_Id],[mediacontent_Id],[orgurl],[newurl],[img])"
        sins = sins + " values(" + CStr(eid) + "," + CStr(mid) + ",'" + tmpURL + "',null, @IMG)"

        sqlConn = DirectCast(Dts.Connections("LocalADO").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sins, sqlConn)
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@IMG", SqlDbType.Image)
        sqlComm.Parameters("@IMG").Value = tmpImg

        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

So, in the end it was simple but I wasted a lot of time before I thought outside the box that I had unwittingly enclosed myself in - that's the biggest lesson here!